# nginx rewrite with 2+ parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I am fairly new to Nginx and doing good so far.  I am trying to cut down on the rewrites so I am writing new ones as I will not need to edit them anymore.

I have the following URL:

http://example.com/en/this-is-my-life

Which needs to be rewritten like"

http://example.com/index.php?page=this-is-my-life&lang=en

Now because "page=" and "lang=" are increasing I need to have a rewrite that will take these 2 parameters of the URI and rewrite them.

I have tried the following but it is not working.  I am using nginx-1.4.2.

> rewrite ^/([a-z])/([a-z-])/$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 last;

Any ideas why it is not working?